# Printing leaf function in single line in a set of nested functions

Tags: c, linux, function, linux-kernel, ftrace

I have a set of nested functions like in `kernel` source. I need to print parent function with opening and closing curly braces, and leaf function in a single line with semicolon similar to ftrace graph tracer. I have the current function 's name but I am not able to bring up the logic to **identify the leaf function** in a set of nested functions. Should I use a counter for each function entry and exit? And then how  do I use that `counter` value? Example :

[image: Function graph tracer]

Comment: Could you post an example of what you're trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @Adrien As in above picture `__fget` is a leaf function which ftrace identifies and ends with a semicolon and not curly braces. How does it identify the leaf function? I want to print function names in a similar way.

Comment: Let me guess, it didn't call any other function and returned.

Comment: `ftrace` uses **tracepoints** at the beginning of each function (I am unsure about tracepoints at the end of the function). When a *tracepoint* fires, information about that is stored in the trace: time, cpu, task, function name. This trace can be represented graphically like in the image you provide. As noted by 0andriy, leaf function is the one which doesn't call other functions (more correctly: doesn't call functions with tracepoints).